# Fast complex SQL queries on PostgreSQL database with Python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, performance, pandas

I have a large dataset with +50M records in a PostgreSQL database that require massive calculations, inner join.

**Python** is the tool of choice with **Psycopg2**.

Running the process with `fetchmany` of 20,000 records takes a couple of hours to finish.

The execution needs to take place sequentially, as in each record of the 50M needs to be fetched separately, then another query (in the below example) needs to run before a result is returned and saved in a separate table.

Indexes are properly configured on each table (5 tables in total) and the complex query (that returns a calculated value - example below) takes around **240MS** to return results (when the database is not under load).

Celery is used to take care of database inserts of the calculated values in a separate table.

My question is about common strategies to reduce overall running time and produce results/calculations faster.
In other words, what is an effective way to go through all the records, one by one, calculate the value of a field via a second query then save the result.

**UPDATE:**

There is an important piece of information that I unintentionally missed mentioning while trying to obfuscate sensitive details. Sorry for that.

The original `SELECT` query calculates a value aggregated from different tables as follows:

```
SELECT CR.gg, (AX.b + BF.f)/CR.d AS calculated_field
FROM table_one CR
  LEFT JOIN table_two AX ON EX.x = CR.x
  LEFT JOIN table_three BF ON BF.x = CR.x
WHERE CR.gg = '123'
GROUP BY CR.gg;
```

PS: the SQL query is written by our experienced DBA so i trust that it is optimised.

Comment: Run the same query *naked* in psql, to get an estimate of the time needed to transfer to/from the pyhon front end , and the time to convert the data to/from the python structures.

Comment: `... and a single query takes around ...` What is a *single query* ??

Comment: @wildplasser a single query as in everytime the dataset is queried (including join commands)
ie:

`select * from table_one er
  left join table_two ex ON ex.x = er.y
  left join table_three ef on ef.x = er.z
where er.gg = '123'
group by er.gg;`

Comment: And: what is a **not** *single query* ??? Note:the `group by er.gg` is useless, since there is only one group (and no aggregates)

Comment: @wilplasser thanks for your input, the group by IS needed.

Since the wording about a single query (or simply a query) is not clear, how would you phrase the question?

Comment: What **is** your *big query*? Or are you executing your `single query` repeatedly (known as *row at a time-processing* ) ?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you again @wildplasser. Indeed, the query is executed repeatedly on each one of the 50M records, to calculate the value of a specific field.

Comment: Well: don't do that! (it will cost two round trips to the database + parse+execute **per item** ) Instead, let the database calculate **all** the values for **all** the records that you need, and fetch **all** the results in **one** sweep.

Answer (score 3):

- don't loop over records and call the DBMS repeatedly for every record.
- instead, let the DBMS process large chunks (preferrably: all) of data
- and, let it spit out *all* the results.

Below is a snippet of my twitter-sucker(with a rather complex *ugly* query)

---

```
def fetch_referred_tweets(self):
    self.curs = self.conn.cursor()
    tups = ()
    selrefd = """SELECT twx.id, twx.in_reply_to_id, twx.seq, twx.created_at
    FROM(
     SELECT tw1.id, tw1.in_reply_to_id, tw1.seq, tw1.created_at
     FROM tt_tweets tw1
     WHERE 1=1
      AND tw1.in_reply_to_id > 0
      AND tw1.is_retweet = False
      AND tw1.did_resolve = False
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tweets nx
                       WHERE nx.id = tw1.in_reply_to_id)
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tt_tweets nx
                       WHERE nx.id = tw1.in_reply_to_id)
     UNION ALL
    SELECT tw2.id, tw2.in_reply_to_id, tw2.seq, tw2.created_at
     FROM tweets tw2
     WHERE 1=1
      AND tw2.in_reply_to_id > 0
      AND tw2.is_retweet = False
      AND tw2.did_resolve = False
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tweets nx
                       WHERE nx.id = tw2.in_reply_to_id)
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tt_tweets nx
                       WHERE nx.id = tw2.in_reply_to_id)
     -- ORDER BY tw2.created_at DESC
    )twx
     LIMIT %s;"""
      # -- AND tw.created_at < now() - '15 min':: interval
      # -- AND tw.created_at >= now() - '72 hour':: interval

    count = 0
    uniqs = 0
    self.curs.execute(selrefd, (quotum_referred_tweets, ) )
    tups = self.curs.fetchmany(quotum_referred_tweets)
    for tup in tups:
      if tup == None: break
      print ('%d -->> %d [seq=%d] datum=%s' % tup)
      self.resolve_list.append(tup[0] ) # this tweet
      if tup[1] not in self.refetch_tweets:
          self.refetch_tweets[ tup[1] ] = [ tup[0]] # referred tweet
          uniqs += 1

      count += 1

    self.curs.close()
```

---

Note: your query makes no sense:

- you only select fields from the `er`table
- so, the two `LEFT JOIN`ed tables could be omitted
- if `ex` and `ef` *do* contain multiple matching rows, the resultset *could* be larger than just all the rows selected from `er`, resulting in duplicated`er` records
- there is a `GROUP BY` present, but no aggregates are in the select list

---

```
select er.gg, er.z, er.y
from table_one er
where er.gg = '123'
-- or:
where er.gg >= '123'
  and er.gg <= '456'
ORDER BY er.gg, er.z, er.y -- Or: some other ordering
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. Your points make total sense, not the ones regarding the query though as I've made a mistake and added an update to clarify the problem. Also, thanks for the code snippet.

Comment: Note:there is no `ez.` alias in scope. Please post the **real** query (plus the table definitions, etc. *plonk?* )

Answer (score 1):

since you are doing a join in your query, the logical thing to do is to work around it, meaning create what's known as a summary table, this summary table -residing on the database- will hold the final joined dataset, so in your python code you will just fetch/select data from it.

another way is to use materialized view [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I took @wildplasser's advice and moved the calculation operation inside the database as a function.
The result has been impressively efficient to say the least and total run time dropped to minutes/~ hour.

To recap:

- Database records are no longer fetched in the sequence
  mentioned earlier
- Calculations happen inside the database via a function [PostgreSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createfunction.html)